# I'd like to create a mock object in python

Tags: python, object, setattr

I want a dummy object I can instantiate in python and programmatically create attributes for via setattr().

I tried it on the built in object but probably for a good reason that didn't work.

What base object can I use in python for such purposes without actually defining one myself?

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `mock = object()`, instead just create a Mock derived from `object`

```
class Mock(object):
    pass

mock = Mock()

setattr(mock, 'test', 'whatever')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mocking library (e.g. [mock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)) then you get to make assertions about what gets called on the object. You may or may not want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to Jon Clement's technique, in case you want your mock object to get some attributes upon creation:

```
class Mock(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwArgs):  # constructor turns keyword args into attributes
       self.__dict__.update(kwArgs)


# now you can do things like this:
options = Mock(verbose=True, debug=False)
```